# Filtering a large relationship subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Consider a simple SQLAlchemy model with a relationship:

```
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ == 'users'

    friends = relationship('User', secondary=friend,
        primaryjoin=id == friend.c.to_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == friend.c.from_id,
        order_by=friends.c.id,
        lazy='subquery')
```

In some pathological cases, a user may have a lot of friends, thus making this query very expensive:

```
user_friends = user.friends
```

How can I execute the same subquery, but e.g. requesting a specific `order_by` and limiting to `N` objects? I'd like to do something like:

```
some_friends = user.friends.order_by('some_field').limit(10)
```

But I couldn't understand from the documentation how to configure those query options **on the subquery**.

**Stop marking this question as a duplicate, the so-called duplicate question has nothing to do with handling subqueries.**

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not at all sure what `lazy='subquery'` really does (even looking at the docs), but in 100% of use-cases for myself, `lazy='dynamic'` works perfectly for this. Since I don't understand `lazy='subquery'` or why you need it, I'm not going to try to answer this question. But if you find you don't actually need it, `lazy='dynamic'` will solve your problem immediately.

Comment: Indeed, thanks guys for the suggestions, I'll just use `lazy='dynamic'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed according to @malan's suggestion, using `lazy='dynamic'` is the easiest solution to this case, if `subquery` isn't explicitly needed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the newer versions (1.3 and up) of SQLAlchemy have introduced a way to create this kind of [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) relationship [using `AliasedClass` and window functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#row-limited-relationships-with-window-functions), if the DBMS in question supports window functions:

```
class User(Base):
    ...

top_friends = select([
        User,
        friend.c.to_id,
        func.row_number().over(partition_by=friend.c.to_id, 
                               order_by=User.some_field).label('index')]).\
    select_from(join(User, friend, User.id == friend.c.from_id)).\
    alias()

friend_user = aliased(User, top_friends)

User.friends = relationship(
    friend_user,
    primaryjoin=and_(User.id == top_friends.c.to_id, top_friends.c.index <= 10))
```